reaviz/reaflow - [v5.3] [Bug] importing anything from the library results in error - Keys is not a function
The recent version of reaviz/reaflow (reaflow) brings breaking changes to my web app. I wanted to use the latest exposed function where we can zoom in on a particular node of tree which can be useful for user to find out any particular tree node in a large tree.

Issue occurs as soon as you import anything from library version 5.3.1
Normally, the error should not come. So far we were using version 5.1.0 which did not cause any issue with our project. recently there was a requirement which could be easily resolved by a function exposed in latest version of this library (fitNodes) but due to this error we cannot upgrade the library.
Any help provided will be appreciated
Issue reported on github as well https://github.com/reaviz/reaflow/issues/265
code sandbox link -> https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reaflow-demo-ptbgs9
Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions
Step 1 -> Setup a react project with following library versions ->

React@18
React-dom@18
React-scripts@5
Step 2 -> Install reaflow@5.3.1 and simply import Canvas component exposed by this library.
Step 3 -> Run the server and you will see an error on console


Node version: have tried with v15, v18, v22
Platform:  Mac
IDE: VS code and Codesandbox env as well

Libs:

react version: 18.0.0
react-dom: 18.0.0
react-scripts: 5.0.0
reaflow: 5.3.1

The issue happens with both webpack and react-scripts compiler
